# com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-mail, smtp-auth

I am trying to send an Email from my Java Application to any particular email address.
I am using Java Mail API but Unfortunately i am getting SMTPSendFailedException error. Can any body tell me where i am doing a mistake. Here is my code

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

//import SeconMail.Authenticator;

public class SendMail
{

   public static void main(String [] args)
   {    

      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = "to@gmail.com";

      // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
      String from = "from@expertflow.com";

      // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
      String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

      // Get system properties
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();

      // Setup mail server

      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);


      properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

      properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
      // Get the default Session object.
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
      session.setDebug(true);

      try{
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText("This is actual message");

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Try `properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");` and you'll probably need username and password too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Elliott , how can i specify username and password? Would you please tell me.

Comment: Hey Malik,is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes Sanjay My problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 6):

```
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "abc");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.password", "xyz");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
```

please try using this

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
final Properties properties = System.getProperties();

// Setting up mail server
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", EMAIL_SMTP_HOST);
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(EMAIL_USERNAME,
                EMAIL_PASSWORD);
    }
});
session.setDebug(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

While creating session override a method `PasswordAuthentication` and in that give username and password.

```
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() 
    {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
        {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("pqr@gmail.com","xyz@123");
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try these

```
String login = "myemailhere";
String pass = "mypasshere";
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", login);
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.password", pass);
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");      

Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(null, login, pass);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it still doesn't work for you try this:

```
properties.setProperty("mail.smtps.ssl.enable", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try also

```
Transport.send(message, user, pass);
```

I have found this in Transport class documentation

> Use the specified user name and password to authenticate to the mail
>   server.

```
public static void send(Message msg, String user, String password) throws MessagingException {

    msg.saveChanges();
    send0(msg, msg.getAllRecipients(), user, password);
}
```

I am Using JavaMail v 1.6.1 and [MailTrap SMTP Server](https://mailtrap.io/)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue recently. I tried to send an email over Gmail server with API key + password auth. `Transport.send(message)` didn't work for me, I debugged it and found out that it ignored session settings attached to the `message`.

This is now I did the email sending over SMTP Gmail server with auth and TLS. I used `com.sun.mail:javax.mail-1.6.1`

```
    String host = "your-email-server-host"; // define your server host here
    int port = 587; // standard port for TLS connection

    // config session properties, here the SMTP protocol is used
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", String.valueOf(port));
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); // enable auth
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); // enable TLS

    // get session instace baed on the settings defined above
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);

    // `prepareMessage` implementation is omitted, construct your own message here
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = prepareMessage(email, session);

    // your credentials       
    String username = "your-username@gmail.com"; // or API key, I used API key
    String password = "your-password";

    // get the transport instance from the freshly created session
    // pass the valid protocol name, here the SMTP is used
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("stmp");

    // connect to the transport instance with your credentials
    transport.connect(host, port, username,password);

    // send the message
    transport.sendMessage(mimeMessage, mimeMessage.getAllRecipients());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "abc");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.password", "xyz");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
```

it worked, fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

For me to make it work with a JHipster application I had to implement my custom JavaMailSenderImpl() because via properties did not work.

Inside the MailService Class create a method:

```
public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
mailSender.setHost("");
mailSender.setPort(587);

mailSender.setUsername("");
mailSender.setPassword("");

Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");

return mailSender;}
```

Then you can use this implementation and go on as normal:

```
JavaMailSender javaMailSender = getJavaMailSender();
MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
```

I think the reason why I had to do this was that my application connected via VPN to the server and there some things got mixed up.