# com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required (Java Mail)

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

So i'm trying to get Java Mail to work and because other answers I've seen of this site are not working, I have to assume somethings have changed in the past year or so. So I apoligies if this question seems like a DUPLICATE I can't figure out why it is not working. The following is my code:

```
try{
        Properties property = new Properties();
        property.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        property.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        //property.setProperty("mail.smpt.port", "25");
        property.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "myEmail@gmail.com");
        property.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        System.out.println("Mail Check 1");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(property);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myEmail@gmail.com"));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("myEmail@gmail.com"));

        System.out.println("Mail Check 2");

        message.setSubject("Oil Error Report");
        message.setText(emailMessage);

        System.out.println("Mail Check 3");

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
        transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com",465,"myEmail@gmail.com","myPassword");
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();

        System.out.println("Mail Sent");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Mail fail");
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

I get up to Mail Check 3 then I get the following exception:

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 u3sm10254140ioi.27 - gsmtp
```

Which doesn't make sense because I have mail.smtp.auth set to true. I have looked at past answers and I have tried to get it to work for while before posting. I'm assuming it's something simple.. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public class EmailSender {    
    public void sendEmail(String emailMessage){

        try{
            final String fromEmail = ""; //requires valid gmail id
            final String password = ""; // correct password for gmail id
            final String toEmail = ""; // can be any email id 

            System.out.println("TLSEmail Start");
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); //SMTP Host
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //TLS Port
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); //enable authentication
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //enable STARTTLS

                //create Authenticator object to pass in Session.getInstance argument
            Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
                //override the getPasswordAuthentication method
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, password);
                }
            };
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));

            System.out.println("Mail Check 2");

            message.setSubject("Oil Error Report");
            message.setText(emailMessage);

            System.out.println("Mail Check 3");

            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Mail Sent");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Mail fail");
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code needed that got it working! It is November 2014 and this currently works for gmail! I hope this code will help save someone time, took much of mine! Along with this code you have to change your email setting to allow emails such as these to be allowed. You will get an email from google the first time you attempt, and it will walk you through on changing the setting.

Thanks and good luck!

Comment: Ahhh it worked for me! Thanks so much. I was having so many errors with my own code. One thing would get fixed and then another would pop up, seemed like it was never ending. You rock.

Comment: Yay! Happy it helped someone! Made all the hard work worth it. Have a great day!

Comment: I had a similar issue few days ago, the code above didn't work for me, I used javax mail 1.6.1. Authenticator wasn't invoked during the `Transport.send(message)` call. I posted my recipe here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49257256/2753863

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the URL?  Did you follow all the steps there?  What happened?

You'll want to fix these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Note that since you're using the "smtps" protocol, **none** of the mail.smtp.* properties apply.  But that's ok because you don't need them anyway due to the way you're calling the connect method.

Comment: Ya I believe I did, I looked the link you sent me, I'm not doing anything they are not... Do you see me doing or not doing something that's on there?